# Calculate multinomial coefficient

Tags: c++, combinatorics, algebra

I want to calculate multinomial coefficient mod 1e9 + 7. It equals: n! / (k0! * k1! * k2 * ... * km!)

In my case m = 3, k0 + k1 + k2 = n, so it would be: n! / (k0! * k1! * k2!) My code for this:

```
....
long long k2 = n - k1 - k0;
long long dans = fact[n] % MOD;
long long tmp = fact[i] % MOD;
tmp = (tmp * fact[j]) % MOD;
tmp = (tpm * fact[k]) % MOD;
res = (fact[n] / tmp) % MOD; // mb mistake is here...
cout << res;
```

fact[i] - factorial of i mod 1e9+7
It does not work on big tests

Comment: Which tests are considered big? Do you think your calculations are overflow-free? BTW `long k2 = n - k1 - k2` is probably not what you want.

Comment: n = 5000 k1 = 123 k0 = 321 is big. About this line... fixed

Comment: Do you know what `5000!` *is*? It has more than 16000 decimal digits.

Comment: I know, that's why I do these % MOD...

Comment: What does the `fact` array contain? At any rate `(x/y) % n != (x % n)/(y % n)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope I'm not linkfarming here, but here is a process of work, to solve your problem :

1. Naive implementations will always suffer from overflow errors. You have to be ready to exploit certain mathematical properties of the polynomial coefficient to reach a robust solution. **Dave Barber** does that in his [library](http://home.comcast.net/~tamivox/dave/multinomial/index.html), where the recursive property is used (example for 4 numbers - the recursion stops when all branches are replaced by zero)

   ```
   multi (a, b, c, d) = multi (a − 1, b, c, d) + multi (a, b − 1, c, d) + multi (a, b, c − 1, d) + multi (a, b, c, d − 1)
   ```
2. Based on the above, **David Serrano Martínez** shows how an [implementation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695644/Multinomial-coefficients-with-overflow-control) that provides overflow control can be divised. His code can be used as easily as

   ```
   unsigned long long result_2 = multinomial::multi<unsigned long long>({9, 8, 4});
   ```
3. A third alternative would be to use (or learn from) libraries that are dedicated to combinatorics, like [SUBSET](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/cpp_src/subset/subset.html). This is a bit more  difficult code to read through due to dependencies and length, but invokation is as easy as

   ```
   int factors[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
   Maths::Combinatorics::Arithmetic::multinomial(4, factors)
   ```

Comment: This question has all the telltale signs of a programming contest. Just sayin'.

Comment: n.m., yep ;) I will try to implement it. I have to brute k0, k1 in my problem, so not sure if using recursion here will be appropriate...

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate [image: sum(ks)! / (k1! * ... * kn!)] by multiplying the numerator down from `sum(ks)` and dividing up in the denominator up from `1`.  The result as you progress will always be integers, because you divide by `i` only after you have first multiplied together `i` contiguous integers.

```py
def multinomial(*ks):
    """ Computes the multinomial coefficient of the given coefficients
    >>> multinomial(3, 3)
    20
    >>> multinomial(2, 2, 2)
    90
    """
    result = 1
    numerator = sum(ks)
    ks = list(ks)       # These two lines are unnecessary optimizations
    ks.remove(max(ks))  # and can be removed
    for k in ks:
        for i in range(k):
            result *= numerator
            result //= i + 1
            numerator -= 1
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this problem, and my solution was to first map to log-space, do the work there, and then map back. This is helpful as we avoid the overflow issues in log-space, and also multiplications become sums which can be more efficient. It may also be useful to work directly with the log-space result.

The maths:

```
C(x1, ..., xn) = sum(x)! / (x1! * ... * xn!)
```

Therefore

```
ln C(x1, ..., xn) = ln sum(x)! - ln {(x1! * ... * xn!)}
                  = sum{k=1->sum(x)} ln k - sum(ln xi!)
                  = sum{k=1->sum(x)} ln k - sum(sum{j=1->xi} (ln j))
```

If any of the `xi`, or `sum(x)` are big (e.g. > 100), then we could actually just use Sterling's approximation:

```
ln x! ~= x * ln x - x
```

Which would give:

```
ln C(x1, ..., xn) ~= sum(x) * ln sum(x) - sum(x) - sum(xi * ln xi - xi)
```

Here's the code. It's helpful to first write a log factorial helper function.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>   // std::transform
#include <numeric>     // std::iota, std:: accumulate
#include <cmath>       // std::log
#include <type_traits> // std::enable_if_t, std::is_integral, std::is_floating_point

template <typename RealType, typename IntegerType,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<RealType>::value>,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<IntegerType>::value>>
RealType log_factorial(IntegerType x)
{
    if (x == 0 || x == 1) return 0;
    if (x == 2) return std::log(2); // can add more for efficiency

    if (x > 100) {
        return x * std::log(x) - x; // Stirling's approximation
    } else {
        std::vector<IntegerType> lx(x);
        std::iota(lx.begin(), lx.end(), 1);
        std::vector<RealType> tx(x);
        std::transform(lx.cbegin(), lx.cend(), tx.begin(),
                       [] (IntegerType a) { return std::log(static_cast<RealType>(a)); });
        return std::accumulate(tx.cbegin(), tx.cend(), RealType {});
    }
}
```

Then the log factorial function is simple:

```
template <typename RealType, typename IntegerType>
RealType log_multinomial_coefficient(std::initializer_list<IntegerType> il)
{
    std::vector<RealType> denoms(il.size());
    std::transform(il.begin(), il.end(), denoms.begin(), log_factorial<RealType, IntegerType>);
    return log_factorial<RealType>(std::accumulate(il.begin(), il.end(), IntegerType {})) -
            std::accumulate(denoms.cbegin(), denoms.cend(), RealType {});
}
```

And finally the multinomial coefficient method:

```
template <typename RealType, typename IntegerType>
IntegerType multinomial_coefficient(std::initializer_list<IntegerType> il)
{
    return static_cast<IntegerType>(std::exp(log_multinomial_coefficient<RealType, IntegerType>(std::move(il))));
}
```

e.g.

```
cout << multinomial_coefficient<double, long long>({6, 3, 3, 5}) << endl; // 114354240
```

For any inputs much greater than this we are going to overflow with built in types, but we can still obtain the log-space result, e.g.

```
cout << log_multinomial_coefficient<double>({6, 3, 11, 5, 10, 8}) << endl; // 65.1633
```

Answer (score -2):

[Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

You can Implement this method :

Here's what I came up with in Python --

```
from math import comb

def Multinomial_Coefficient(R:list|tuple):
# list R is assumed to be summing up to n
    Ans = 1
    for i in range(len(R)):
        Ans *= comb(sum(R[:i+1]), R[i])
    return Ans
```