# Calculate this factorial term in C++ with basic datatypes

Tags: c++, algorithm, factorial

I am solving a programming problem, and in the end the problem boils down to calculating following term:

```
n!/(n1!n2!n3!....nm!)
n<50000
(n1+n2+n3...nm)<n
```

I am given that the final answer will fit in 8 byte. I am using C++. How should I calculate this. I am able to come up with some tricks but nothing concrete and generalized.

EDIT:
I would not like to use external libraries.

EDIT1 :
Added conditions and result will be definitely 64 bit int.

Comment: Usually, both `long long` and `double` are 64 bits, i.e. 8 bytes.

Comment: I agree that I will have to use long long and I couldn't understand the order of calculation. I certainly can't calculate the numerator first and denominator next, since it will overflow.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721796/how-do-you-implement-the-factorial-function-in-c

Comment: ^ Doesn't matter, temporaries will overflow very quickly. You'll need to evaluate the expression in a way that each intermediate value will fit in your 8-byte variable. I'm not sure what your denominator is supposed to be from what you have written.

Comment: In most cases the answer is a rational number, so what representation do you plan ? Is there any bound on the n's ?

Comment: I added some clarifications in the edit. Sorry that the problem was missing these earlier.

Comment: Duplicate of [Calculate multinomial coefficient](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22892138/calculate-multinomial-coefficient) Reducing via the recurrence relation will keep the numbers small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the result is *guaranteed to be an integer*, work with the factored representation.

By the [theorem of Legendre](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml), you can express all these factorials by the sequence of exponents of the primes in the range (2,n).

By deducting the exponents of the factorials in the denominator from those in the numerator, you will obtain exponents for the whole quotient. The computation will then reduce to a product of primes that will never overflow the 8 bytes.

For example,

```
25! = 2^22.3^10.5^6.7^3.11^2.13.17.19.23
15! = 2^11.3^6.5^3.7^2.11.13
10! = 2^8.3^4.5^2.7
```

yields

```
25!/(15!.10!) = 2^3.5.11.17.19.23 = 3268760
```

The exponents of, say, 3 are found by

```
25/3 + 25/9 = 10
15/3 + 15/9 = 6
10/3 + 10/9 = 4
```

Comment: You don't really need the result to be an integer, do you ? Negative exponents will take their natural interpretation in the result.  Otherwise +1 for using Legendre's theorem

Comment: @vib: You do otherwise intermediate results can overflow.

Comment: Which intermediate result ?

Comment: When computing the product of the powers of the primes.

Comment: @YvesDaoust This seems correct answer to me. There's a small typo in 15/3 + 19/9 . But this should work. I will try to implement it. Thanks.

Comment: @YvesDaoust   Could you be more specific ? I don't see where you compute product of powers of primes ? Once you got you decomposition you just add the exponents.  -- I agree that this is a rather pointless discussion though as only few rational numbers admit an exact binary representation and they correspond only to very peculiar case of the multinomial coefficient.

Comment: @vib: hem, isn't the answer a product of primes that you need to compute ?

Answer (score 2):

If all the input (not necessarily the output) is made of integers, you could try to count prime factors. You create an array of size sqrt(n) and fill it with the counts of each prime factor in n :

```
vector <int> v = vector <int> (sqrt(n)+1,0);
int m = 2;
while (m <=n) {
    int i = 2;
    int a = m;
    while (a >1) {
        while (a%i ==0) {
            v[i] ++;
            a/=i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    m++;
}
```

Then you iterate over the n_k (1 <= k <= m) and you decrease the count for each prime factor. This is pretty much the same code as above except that you replace the v[i]++ by v[i] --. Of course you need to call it with vector v previously obtained.

After that the vector v contains the list of count of prime factors in your expression and you just need to reconstruct the result as

```
int result = 1;
for (int i = 2; i < v.size(); v++) {
    result *= pow(i,v[i]);
}
return result;
```

Note : you should use long long int instead of int above but I stick to int for simplicity

**Edit** : As mentioned in another answer, it would be better to use Legendre theorem to fill / unfill the vector v faster.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use the properties of the logarithm:

```
log(AB) = log(A) + log(B)

log(A/B) = log(A) - log(B)
```

and

```
X = e^(log(X))
```

So you can first compute the logarithm of your quantity, then exponentiate back:

```
log(N!/(n1!n2!...nk!)) = log(1) + ... + log(N) - [log(n1!) - ... log(nk!)]
```

then expand `log(n1!)` etc. so you end up writing everything in terms of logarithm of single numbers. Then take the exponential of your result to obtain the initial value of the factorial.

As @T.C. mentioned, this method may not be to accurate, although in typical scenarios you'll have many terms reduced. Alternatively, you expand each factorial into a list that stores the terms in its product, e.g. `6!` will be stored in a list `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`. You do the same for the denominator terms. Then you start removing common elements. Finally, you can take gcd's and reduce everything to coprime factors, then compute the result.

Comment: That's unlikely to be very accurate.

Comment: @T.C. probably there should be more clever ways. However for typical coefficients lots of terms will disappear, so it may not be too bad. When I posted the answer I thought about the problem more from a mathematical point of view, where errors are non-existent :) Otherwise one can just use a list and eliminate all common factors, then start taking gcds until everything is coprime, then finally compute the result.